My state is not changing while the api request is correct
I am using Redux and when I send a get request to authenticate user it is working, creating a token in cookies, but in Redux the state is not changing. What am I doing wrong? When reloading the page my token and user data are valid, here are some code samples.
After successful login my state is:
{
  "user": {
    "isAuthenticated": false
  }
}

Yet is should be true
I logged in before useEffect and it says true, because I have token its correct, so how do I pass it inside useEffect or when page is opened? I want to toast when it is true.
User reducer:
import { createReducer } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
}

export const userReducer = createReducer(initialState, (builder) => {
  builder
    .addCase('AuthenticateUserRequest', (state) => {
      state.loading = true
    })
    .addCase('AuthenticateUserSuccess', (state, action) => {
      state.isAuthenticated = true
      state.user = action.payload
      state.loading = false
    })
    .addCase('AuthenticateUserFailure', (state, action) => {
      state.isAuthenticated = false
      state.error = action.payload
      state.loading = false
    })
    .addCase('ClearErrors', (state) => {
      state.error = null
    })
})

User action:
import axios from "axios"
import { authenticateUserUrl } from '../../constants'

export const authenticateUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: 'AuthenticateUserRequest'
    })

    const { data } = await axios.get(authenticateUserUrl, { withCredentials: true })

    dispatch({
      type: 'AuthenticateUserSuccess',
      payload: data.user,
    })
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: 'AuthenticateUserFailure',
      payload: err.response.data.message
    })
  }
}

store:
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import { userReducer } from "./reducers/user"

const Store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userReducer,
  },
})
  
export default Store

app:
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react"
import { authenticateUser } from "./redux/actions/user"

const App = () => {
  var store = useContext(ReactReduxContext).store.getState()

  useEffect(() => {
    Store.dispatch(authenticateUser)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(store))  
  })


state updates are not synchronous. Have your console log outside the useEffect and you'll see it log false on the initial render pass(es), and then because you're updating the state, it'll log true on the next render pass. Also, your useEffect is going to run every single render pass right now, which is almost certainly not what you want. And last, useEffect is for running code that has "not-React-managed side effects" (e.g. updating the DOM outside of React's control, calling some external API, etc). If your code is just "more application logic", use useCallback.

okay I logged in before useEffect and it says true, because I have token its correct, so how do I pass it inside I want to toast when it is true

That sounds like a different question from what you've posted, so probably [edit] your post to focus on that.

What is Store in the effect callback where it calls Store.dispatch(authenticateUser)? The store you are logging is going to be stale when logging it, so why not use console.log(JSON.stringify(Store.getState())) to access the current store value?

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans But Redux state updates are synchronous, that's what makes working with and using Redux as a state machine valuable. Dispatch an action and a pure synchronous reducer function consumes the current state and action and produces the next state value. The problem OP has is just a Javascript Closure issue where they are logging a stale value.

Issue
The issue here is that of a stale Javascript closure. Redux state updates are synchronous, but you are attempting to console log the store value from the render cycle prior to the effect running.
const App = () => {
  var store = useContext(ReactReduxContext).store.getState(); // <-- accessed here

  useEffect(() => {
    Store.dispatch(authenticateUser) ;  // <-- updates state
    console.log(JSON.stringify(store)); // <-- still old value from outer closure
  })

  ...
};

Solution
You can access the store using the useStore hook and then access the current state value in the effect callback.
const App = () => {
  const store = useStore();

  useEffect(() => {
    store.dispatch(authenticateUser);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(store.getState()));
  }, []);

  ...
};

Using the useStore hook and dispatch and getState methods are not the normal way of accessing the store in a React component. It's far more common to use the useDispatch and useSelector hooks to dispatch actions to the store and subscribe to changes from the store. Use a separate effect to log the user state when it updates.
Example:
const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const user = useSelector(state => state.user);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(authenticateUser);
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
  }, [user]);

  ...
};


Well turns out the solution is:
const { isAuthenticated, user, loading, error } = useSelector((state) => state.user)
    
      useEffect(() => {
        Store.dispatch(authenticateUser()) // Dispatch the action once on component mount
      }, []) // Empty dependency array to ensure this runs only once
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (isAuthenticated) {
          console.log("User State:", { isAuthenticated, user, loading, error })
        }
      }, [isAuthenticated, user, loading, error]) 

